# Rigify tail bones doesn't generate controls

Tags: rigging, bones, cloth-simulation, rigify

[image]

I added tail bones too my characters clothes but they do not generate controls, only the body does.

I just got tail bones put them in place and paired them so what step am I missing or is there a better way too do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Rigify that your added tail bones should be a tail. This is done by setting the *Rigify Type* to `spines.basic_tail` for the base bone of the tail. Then it will generate the control bones for the tail as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot rigify type]