# Adding rigging to new bones?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a character with tendrils growing out of it's back, so to be able to animate them I had to create new bones for them. I read in a thread here that you can assign vertex groups to influence parts of the mesh, and I have done that but it doesn't have any effect.

When I rigify no "handles" are created for those bones and if I move a bone in edit mode, the mesh is not affected, even if I parent the mesh to the skeleton. What do I have to do to be able to animate the tendrils?

[image]

Comment: Are the bones part of the armature the body is parented to? Do they have the same name as the vertex groups that they are supposed to move? Also, moving the bones in Edit mode won't move the mesh, you need to be in Pose mode. Maybe share your file (remove the head for example if you don't want to share everything)?

Comment: To generate "handles" (control bones) you need to define a Rigify Type for the tendrils bones. Have a look here:https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252604/107598

Comment: I managed to generate control bones for the added bones but they deform parts of the hands of the mesh(they are de-attached), which they shouldn't. I noticed my vertice groups had been changed by themselves(I have no idea how that happened), so I tried to redo them and remove all parents everywhere. But for some reason the rig still works. Not even re-generating the rig fixes it. I'll upload it so you can take a look if you have time. https://easyupload.io/96gy6z